# Como hacer responsive una imagen en un background dentro de un select en flecha!

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

espero y se encuentren bien, lo que pasa es que tengo un problema al hacer responsive la flecha de un elemento "select" o "comboBox" aqui esta el codigo css donde se carga la imagen:

```
.selectArrow {
    background: URL(../img/unfold-icon.png) no-repeat 416px 16px #f4f4f4 !important;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding-left: 24px;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
      display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
    /*    appearance: none;*/

}
```

Y lo que me arroja en la vista del responsive es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya por ultimo pondria mi html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
        <!--<script src="../comun/js/jquery_v1.11.3.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../comun/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../comun/js/EnmascaraV2-AEM.js"></script>-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_MD_cta.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DataLayer/dataLayer.js"></script><!--listo-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DataLayer/dataLayer_.js"></script><!--listo-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DataLayer/funciones_dataLayer.js"></script><!--listo-->

        <script src="//assets.adobedtm.com/95bb966a4c61b200a089c37679aaf96e22114787/satelliteLib-fbdb84ebd99368b1f7fb97b75596c095b9f7ee40-staging.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!--listo-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/seleccion.js"></script><!--listo-->

        <script src="//assets.adobedtm.com/95bb966a4c61b200a089c37679aaf96e22114787/mbox-contents-a552a4edacd46d5f42cf557b1157973f26c55845.js"></script>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#seguro').val('');
                $('#pension').val('');
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Simulador Pensión</h1>
            <h2>Descubre a través de este simulador, cual podría ser un aproximado del monto de Pensión que
                recibirás de acuerdo a los datos que nos proporciones.</h2>
            <form name="index" method="post" action="views/paso-02.jsp">

                <div class="botonera">      
                    <div id="bt_div" class="derecha">
                        <div class="group">
                            <select  name="seguro" class="selectArrow" class="Caja_txt_246" tabindex="9" id="seguro" onchange="Opciones()" >
                                <option value="" selected="">--Seleccione--</option>
                                <option value="1" id="TDSIV">Invalidez y Vida</option>
                                <option value="2" id="TDSRT">Riesgo de trabajo</option>
                                <option value="3" id="TDSRCV">Retiro y Cesantía</option>
                            </select>
                            <label class="combo">Tipo de Seguro</label>
                        </div>
                        <p class=" cond SP_alert"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bt_div" class="izquierda">
                        <div class="group">
                            <div id="DivPension">
                                <select class="selectArrow" name="pension" class="Caja_txt_246" id="pension" tabindex="9">
                                    <option value="" selected="">--Seleccione--</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <label class="combo">Tipo de Pensión</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="botonera">      
                    <div id="bt_div" class="izquierda">
                        <button type="submit" id="loginButton"  onclick="validar(event);" >Siguiente</button>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </form>
        </div>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

            setVersionDL();
            setPageInstanceID("des");
            setPageIntent("informacion");
            setPageSegment("personas");
            setSysEnv("escritorio");
            setChannel("online");
            setLanguage("ES");
            setGeoRegion("MX");
            setLevel(1, "pensiones");
            setLevel(2, "simulador pensiones");
            setLevel(3, "1 seleccion tipo de seguro");
            setArea("publica");
            setPageName();
            setServer();
            setBussinessUnit("BBVA Bancomer");
            setMobile();
            setUserState("no logado");
            setType("simulador");
            setName("simulador pensiones");
            setFulfillmentModel("online");
            setStep("1 seleccion del tipo de seguro");
            setState("inicio");
            setPrimaryCategory("inversiones");
            setProductName("");
            setProductSubtype("planes de pensiones");
            setUserAgent();
        </script>    
        <script>



    function validar(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //obteniendo el valor que se puso en el campo text del formulario
    var miCombo = document.getElementById("seguro").value;
    var miCombo2 = document.getElementById("pension").value;

    //la condici�n

    if (miCombo == "") {
//        alert('*Seleccione una opcion en seguro. \n');
$(".SP_alert").text("*Seleccione una opcion en seguro. \n");
$("#SP").css("border-bottom", "solid 1px #D44B50");
     $(".SP_alert").show();
    $( ".selectArrow" ).removeClass();
    $("select").css("background-color", "#FCDFDF");


    } else if (miCombo2 == "") {
//        alert('*Seleccione una opcion en pension. \n');
$(".SP_alert").text("*Seleccione una opcion en pension. \n");
    $( ".selectArrow" ).removeClass();
    $("select").css("background-color", "#FCDFDF");
    $(".SP_alert").show();
    $("#SP").css("border-bottom", "solid 1px #D44B50");
    } else
        document.index.submit(event);
}

        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">_satellite.pageBottom();</script>



    </body>



</html>
```

Lo que quiero es mover al momento de que se haga el responsive, espero y me puedan ayudar con este problema que me impide avanzar, de antemano les mando un cordial.

Comment: Hola Amigos ya lo pude solucionar, estaba mal en los pixeles, y solo se lo cambie a porcentaje y lo deje en 100% dentro de donde esta la regla de la imagen, donde dice 416px.

Comment: Si encontraste tu error te invito a que lo publiques como respuesta y luego la aceptes, para saber como responderla puedes leer [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Ya veo que diste con una solución, sin embargo para optimizarlo un poquito más, puedes darle el porcentaje del `width` al contenedor y no a la imagen. Pues al achicarse, es casi seguro que la flecha se hará más angosta también. Puedes probar algo así para que eso no suceda:

```css
.selectArrow {
    width: 100%; /* Modifica el ancho a tu gusto */ 
    height: 60px /* Dale el alto que necesites */ 
    background: url(../img/unfold-icon.png) center center no-repeat #f4f4f4;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Al `background` le agregué la propiedad `center center`, que es lo mismo a colocar: `background-position: center center` (el primer valor alinea el eje Y al centro y el segundo en X). Con eso logras que tu imagen esté bien centrada en todo momento. Además, le agregué al contenedor la propiedad `overflow: hidden`, esto con la finalidad de que al achicarse el contenedor, la imagen no se desborde, sino que se oculte todo el espacio sobrante fuera del contenedor.

El resto de propiedades que ya tienes en tu contenedor, se las puedes agregar al ejemplo que te di.

Espero te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Hola @Yeff Espinoza! No estaria mal probar tu codigo, muchas y que andes bien :)

Answer (score 0):

Hola Amigos ya lo pude solucionar, estaba mal en los pixeles, y solo se lo cambie a porcentaje y lo deje en 100% dentro de donde esta la regla de la imagen, donde dice 416px, asi como quedo amigos XDD Y

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]